# Visual Studio publish as EXE or MSI installer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, windows-installer, exe, publish

I don't really know why, but I am not a big fan of this new "clickonce" installer. Is there any way to have visual studio export an old MSI or EXE installer instead of the clickonce?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I'm not a fan of it either...)

Just go to New Project -> Other Project Types -> Setup and Deployment -> Visual Studio Installer.

You might also like the [Windows Installer XML (WiX) Toolset](http://wix.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Note that VS setup & deployment project was retired in favor of InstallShield limited edition: http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/2010/09/installsite-microsoft-will-retire.html

Answer (score 0):

There are also several 3rd party extension which adds new Setup projects into Visual Studio, e.g. this one: [Visual Studio marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=unSignedsro.VisualInstaller)

That will allow you to create **NSIS** or **Inno Setup** installers directly from IDE with all features like syntax highlighting, code completion and so on.